# Company limited by guarantee - can minors be guarantors?

Tags: united-kingdom, limited-liability-company

In the case of companies described as a "Private company limited by guarantee without share capital", I understand that all Members of the company act as guarantors.  In the case of it winding up, their liability is limited by the articles to a nominal fee (£1).

I understand that in a company limited by shares, there is no automatic prohibition on minors being shareholders, but they may not be bound contractually in some ways.

What happens in the case of a company limited by guarantee?  Can a minor enter into a contract of guarantee in this case, and be held to paying £1 on the dissolution of the company?  If not, does that mean minors cannot be Members of the company?

I can't seem to find anything relevant in the Companies Act 2006 - any sources for relevant information would be appreciated.

Comment: If a minor enters a contract, they or their guardians can void the contract any time until a short time after they are of full age. I don't know if they can become guarantors, but if they do, it's not much of a guarantee since they can void it.

Comment: That was also my understanding - but does that mean that they can be Members of the company, with the only repercussion that their guarantee may be invalid if the company winds up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no statutory provision prohibiting a minor from being a subscriber of a company limited by guarantee. It is possible that the company's articles of association prohibit minors from becoming subscribers.

I am unable to locate any case law on the matter either. Therefore, as long as there's no contractual bar to becoming a subscriber (through the articles of association), I see no reason why a minor cannot subscribe to a company and offer  a guarantee.

It will, of course, be voidable at their own discretion until they turn 18, but that is a risk the company will be taking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, one must be legally of age to enter into a binding contract, and generally also to own titled property, unless a conservator has been appointed for them, or the property is held by some other fiduciary (e.g. a trustee or custodian) on their behalf.

Comment: I was under the impression that minors could enter into contracts, but those contracts were voidable?  I don't think property comes into this discussion as they are not shareholders but potentially guarantors - correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Riot A voidable guarantee is pretty much meaningless. Any time it was called it would be voided.

Comment: Of course.  In this case it could only be called in the case of dissolution of the company - but does that in any way preclude the minor being given status of "member" in the company?

Comment: @Riot Probably.